# Error "must not be null" in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, inputstream, zipinputstream

There are multiple files in a .zip file, which I'm trying to get. Trying to unzip the files provides a java.lang.IllegalStateException: zis.nextEntry must not be null. How to do it the right way?

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun unzip(zipFile: File, targetDirectory: File) {
        val zis = ZipInputStream(
                BufferedInputStream(FileInputStream(zipFile)))
        try {
            var ze: ZipEntry
            var count: Int
            val buffer = ByteArray(8192)
            ze = zis.nextEntry
            while (ze != null) {
                val file = File(targetDirectory, ze.name)
                val dir = if (ze.isDirectory) file else file.parentFile
                if (!dir.isDirectory && !dir.mkdirs())
                    throw FileNotFoundException("Failed to ensure directory: " + dir.absolutePath)
                if (ze.isDirectory)
                    continue
                val fout = FileOutputStream(file)
                try {
                    count = zis.read(buffer)
                    while (count != -1) {
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, count)
                        count = zis.read(buffer)
                    }
                } finally {
                    fout.close()
                    zis.closeEntry()
                    ze = zis.nextEntry
                }
            }
        } finally {
            zis.closeEntry()
            zis.close()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code where you calling the method.

Answer (score 12):

The `ZipEntry` you read from the stream will be `null` when you reach the end of the file, so you have to make the variable that you store it in nullable:

```
var ze: ZipEntry?
```

You were allowed to assign the values you read to a non-nullable variable because they had the platform type `ZipEntry!`, since it's a Java API - in this case you have to determine whether it can be `null`. See the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) about platform types for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You define the variable `ze` like this `var ze: ZipEntry`. So the type is `ZipEntry` and not `ZipEntry?` (nullable type).

If you change `var ze: ZipEntry` by `var ze: ZipEntry?`, the variable can be null.

You can check the doc for [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html). It's one of the big thing with Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to build this functionality that lead me here. Once I made zipEntry nullable an error popped up in an if statement which said zipEntry? is a mismatch to zipEntry, I was able to solve that by using zipEntry!! guaranteeing it was not null.

```
      while(zippedFile != null) {
            fileName = zippedFile.name //It wasn't able to smart cast once zipEntry was nullable
            if (zippedFile.isDirectory) {} //Here it had a type mismatch
```

This was the solution I was able to work out.

```
  while(zippedFile != null) {
            fileName = zippedFile!!.name //Adding !! (not null) allowed it to safely smart cast
            if (zippedFile!!.isDirectory) {} //Here adding not null removed the type mismatch
```

If anyone working in Kotlin runs into this issue I hope it can help!